# Query issue in finding shortest route

Tags: sql

```
Row No  Bus No  Kilometer     From     To
1           10    100        Salem     Trichy
2           11    150        Trichy    Madurai
3           12    180        madurai   Chennai
4           13    50         Salem     coimbatore
5           14    200       coimbatore  chennai
6           15   300        Salem      Chennai
```

This is my table(sample values).I need to find shortest route between Salem and Chennai in terms of Kilometers(min) for example

```
Route 1 : Salem->Trichy,Trichy->Madurai,Madurai->Chennai   Kilometer-430
Route 2:  Salem->coimbatore,coimbatore->chennai            kilometer -250
Route 3:  Selam->Chennai                                   kilometer -300
```

here min is Route 2 - 250 Kilometer.

please help in framing query for this.

Comment: What database are you using?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: hey @Rekha do want the display the **Trichy->Madurai** this type of via or just like **trichy**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this one is simple format like following as:

```
SELECT A.id,A.bus_no,B.from,B.to,B.via,B.km 
FROM a A INNER JOIN b B ON A.r_id=B.r_id
     ORDER BY a.id;
```

[image: a]
[image: b]
[image: result]

note:

1. the r_id is route id.
2. the id is row no.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to use recursion, not sure what db you're using, but if SQL Server:

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT *
                    ,[From]+'>'+[To] AS Trip
                    ,Kilometer AS Trip_Distance
              FROM Table1
              WHERE [From] = 'Salem'
              UNION ALL
              SELECT a.*
                    ,Trip = b.Trip+'>'+a.[To]
                    ,Trip_Distance = b.Trip_Distance + a.Kilometer
              FROM Table1 a
              JOIN cte b
               ON a.[From] = b.[To]
              )
SELECT Trip, Trip_Distance
FROM cte
WHERE [To] = 'Chennai'
ORDER BY Trip_Distance
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/139e1/7/0)

Note: If your `From` and `To` aren't `VARCHAR(MAX)` you'll have to deal with making the lengths match up between recursive portion and anchor.